# Hide server ip adress in browser addressbar after redirected

Tags: .htaccess, server, ip, apache2

I do have a domain "www.mydomain.com" which redirects into a folder on a server:

```
"www.mydomain.com" -> "81.169.120.21/myfolder/"
```

When i vistit "www.mydomain.com" the browser adressbar shows (of course):

```
81.169.120.21/myfolder/index.php
```

Is there a waythat the adress bar stays with "mydomain.com/index.php"?

- Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: You'd have to set up a proxy on  `mydomain.com`, which likely isn't an option. Otherwise there's just frame redirects and they're horrible. Do you have no way of associating the domain with the server directly through the domain's DNS records?

Comment: Thank you, I was not familiar with DNS-Records. I have tried to set the A-Record to my server ip which seems to work, but how do I route into a folder?

Comment: You'd want to set up a `VirtualHost` on the server. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts just remember to also add `Require all granted` to the Virtualhost definition (new in Apache 2.4)

Comment: As a newbie DNS-Records and Virtualhosts were new to me. Your solution with the tutorial gave me all answers I had and its working awesome. Thank you Pekka!